# Pandas Group By - Separate by Time and Condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that I am trying to create sub event_ids based on two conditions - time and a flag. The flag is when people >= 600, create a new subgroup.

The data looks something like this:

```
    | event_id   |  timestamp |  people |
    |  abc       |  12:00     |   1     |
    |  abc       |  12:01     |   3     |
    |  abc       |  12:02     |   5     |
    |  abc       |  12:04     |   600   |
    |  abc       |  12:10     |   4     |
    |  abc       |  12:15     |   7     |
    |  abc       |  12:20     |   1700  |
    |  abc       |  12:30     |   1     |
    |  abc       |  12:31     |   1     |
    |  xyz       |  12:32     |   1     |
    |  xyz       |  12:40     |   750   |
    |  xyz       |  12:50     |   1     |
```

and the result I would like would look like this:

```
    | event_id   |  timestamp |  people |  subgroup  |
    |  abc       |  12:00     |   1     |      A     |
    |  abc       |  12:01     |   3     |      A     |
    |  abc       |  12:02     |   5     |      A     |
    |  abc       |  12:04     |   600   |      A     |
    |  abc       |  12:10     |   4     |      B     |
    |  abc       |  12:15     |   7     |      B     |
    |  abc       |  12:20     |   1700  |      B     |
    |  abc       |  12:30     |   1     |      C     |
    |  abc       |  12:31     |   1     |      C     |
    |  xyz       |  12:32     |   1     |      A     |
    |  xyz       |  12:40     |   750   |      A     |
    |  xyz       |  12:50     |   1     |      B     |
```

So it needs some sort of group by to account for the different event_ids (here abc and xyz but there are millions in my real data set). The data is time ordered, and row order matters when determining the grouping - rows for a event_id between two flags are in one subgroup. Each subgroup belongs in a event_id and counting for the subgroups restarts for a new event_id.

Would love to see any/all ideas, I'm stumped but playing with lambda functions now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

m = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))

def trickery(x):
    c = (x.values >= 600)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
    return c.max() - c

df.assign(subgroup=df.groupby('event_id').people.transform(trickery).map(m))

   event_id timestamp  people subgroup
0       abc     12:00       1        A
1       abc     12:01       3        A
2       abc     12:02       5        A
3       abc     12:04     600        A
4       abc     12:10       4        B
5       abc     12:15       7        B
6       abc     12:20    1700        B
7       abc     12:30       1        C
8       abc     12:31       1        C
9       xyz     12:32       1        A
10      xyz     12:40     750        A
11      xyz     12:50       1        B
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed - the fact it's generalizable to more than ABC subgroups was also what I needed but didn't state in the question... thanks for reading my mind and answering lightning fast :D

Answer (score 3):

```
df.groupby('event_id').people.apply(lambda x :(x>=600).shift().fillna(0).cumsum()).\
    map({0:'A',1:'B',2:'C'})
Out[207]: 
0     A
1     A
2     A
3     A
4     B
5     B
6     B
7     C
8     C
9     A
10    A
11    B
Name: people, dtype: object
```

Then you need just assign it back .

Comment: This answers perfectly too, but I accepted the other because I needed more than A/B/C subgroups but didn't state that in the question. So that's my fault, but your answer is great and I think would be helpful to someone who had specific names like "truck", "car", "plane" that they'd need to assign.

Comment: @LoisKeller ;-) have a nice day